# How can I show images on load with Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to hide an image until it is loaded, and then use the `onload` method to call a jQuery function that shows it. I use the angular `ng-repeat` property `$index` to assign a unique ID to each image div. The `$index` property works, since all my images have ID's like `img0`, `img1`, and so on. My problem is that `onload` is not passing the angular variable, which contains the unique div ID, to my function. Are angular variables unable to be used inside the `onload` method? If not, how can I make it so?

```
<div class="hello" ng-repeat="artist in artists" ng-hide="!artiste">
    <div class="paintings" id="img{({$index})}" style="display:none;">
        <a href="{({ artist.fields.link })}">
            <img src="{({ artist.fields.link })}" onload="showImageDiv(img{({$index})})" />
        </a>

        <h3> {({ artist.fields.title })} </h3>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
     function showImageDiv(imageDivId){   // never receives imageDivId
         $('#' + imageDivId).show();
     };
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you pass `this`: `showImageDiv(this)` ? Then use `$(this).closest('.paintings').show();` inside handler to target DIV. BTW, why are you setting IDs here, seems superflue to me. But anyway, i'm quite sure there is a better way using the angular logic instead of using jQuery but i'm not an angular developper, so...

Comment: That doesn't work. Nothing is getting passed from `onload = "this: showImageDiv(this)"` to my function.

Comment: I am setting IDs because I want the images to be shown in order, one after another. If my function goes simply `$('.paintings').show()` then the images seem to load all at once or out of order, and they even seem to show before they are finished loading, which doesn't work for me.

Comment: `onload="showImageDiv(this)"` not `onload = "this: showImageDiv(this)"`

Comment: Very interesting, I tried your code and it works. However it loads all the images at once, asynchronously, and they end up being out of order, which is why I am trying to keep things in order by assigning IDs.

Comment: because onload event is fired once each specific image is loaded which takes more or less time depending network connection and image weight, so there is no relevant order. `I am trying to keep things in order` Why that?

Comment: The order that the images are displayed is important since it's supposed to be chronological.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work this way - attribute onload is not a directive, so its value is not parsed by angular. You could use a custom directive though, for example (assuming there is a "myModule" module defined):

```
angular.module("myModule").directive("showOnLoad", function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on("load", function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.artist.visible = true;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

It would set the artist.visible field value to `true` after the `load` event. This should work after some changes to the markup:

```
<div class="paintings" ng-show="artist.visible">
    <a href="{{ artist.fields.link }}">
    <img ng-src="{{ artist.fields.link }}" show-on-load /></a>
    <h3> {{ artist.fields.title }} </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-init` instead. Replace

```
onload="showImageDiv(img{({$index})})"
```

with

```
 ng-init="showImageDiv($index)"
```

And since you are using angular, make use of your `controller`. Inside your controller, write this:

```
$scope.showImageDiv = function(index){
 jQuery('#img'+index).show();
}
```

**Update** :

You can also make use of `ng-show`, instead of `jQuery`:

```
<img src="{({ artist.fields.link })}" ng-init="showImageDiv($index)" ng-show="img[$index]" />
```

And in `controller`:

```
$scope.img=[];
$scope.showdiv = function(index){
   $scope.img[index] = true;
}
```

Comment: This is passing the `$index` to my function, which is great, however the `.show()` method is not working and my divs are remaining hidden.

Comment: @edmund_spenser. Updated my answer. You can do it `angular way`. Make use of `ng-show`.